# How to copy grepped files using Find, Grep and Exec in Git Bash

Tags: bash, grep, find, exec, copy

I've looked everywhere for an answer and nothing seems to be working out. In Git Bash, I need to figure out how to take files found with grep and copy them elsewhere. The instructions were to use the find, grep and exec commands to do so. I've found the files I need to copy using the grep command (i.e. grep -rli [search terms] *), so how do I put that in a find exec command to copy?

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
find . -name "*.exe" -exec cp {} ~/Documents \;
```

Not sure why you need to use exec, but otherwise you could use for example:

```
find . -name "*.exe" | grep something | xargs cp -t ~/Documents
find . -name "*.exe" | grep something | xargs -I {} cp {} ~/Documents # more intuitive with placeholders
```

Comment: Thank you, I corrected with ".*exe"

Comment: That's not what the OP needs. The OP is looking for search terms *inside* the file, not in the file name (`grep -rli [search terms]`). (Also, strictly speaking, piping `find` output to `xargs` should not be done without `find … -print0` and `xargs -0`, otherwise this will break if file names contain newlines.)